# Display all Posts by their category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a posts model and a category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  attr_accessible :name

end

Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
 attr_accessible :comments, :title, :category_id, :user_id, :photo

end
```

What I am trying to do is reuse (apply the DRY principle) when using the @posts instance variable in my app. I think im getting in a muddle somewhere. Each post has its own category.

In my view i have all the categories listed

```
<% @categories.each do |c, v| %>
 <li><%= link_to c, blog_path(:name => c) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
 def blog
if params[:month]
      date = Date.parse("1 #{params[:month]}")  # to get the first day of the month
      @posts = Post.where(:created_at => date..date.end_of_month)  # get posts for the month
    elsif params[:name]
      @posts = Post.where(:name => params[:name])
    else
      @posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
end

     @latest = Post.latest_posts
     @posts_by_month = Post.all.group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }

     #Category Section down side of page
     @categories = Category.all.group_by { |c| c.name }
end
```

What i want to achieve is to click a category and then it will display all posts that belong to that category, at the moment when clicking a category link i get

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'posts.name' in 'where clause': SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`  WHERE `posts`.`name` = 'Ruby'
```

Comment: you still have not stated your problem ? :)

Comment: ive added small update to bottom of question, but i thought it was quite straight forward? i want to click on a category link, ie Ruby and then it will display all posts that have that category

Comment: It seems like your posts table doesn't have a name column. Have you added the colum and run the migration?

Comment: @Neo yes thats because name is an attribute within the category model not the posts model, im trying to build upon the answer you provided in a previous question using the if/else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace this line

```
@posts = Post.where(:name => params[:name])
```

with

```
category = Category.where(:name => params[:name]).first
@posts = category.posts
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it symply by

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
 <li><%= link_to c, blog_path(:category_id => c.id) %></li>
<% end %>
```

in controller

```
def blog

  category_id = params[:category_id]
  @category = Category.find(category_id)
  @posts = @category.posts.order("posts.created_at DESC")

end
```